# Get new variable with elements from a double matrix & cell array given a specific condition

Tags: matlab, double, cell, string-matching

I am working with Matlab, and I have a cell array with 5 columns and half million rows and a double matrix with columns and about a quarter million rows. Let’s call them A and B.  A has both string and number elements.

There is one element that is common in both cells, although the number of rows and order is not equal. What I would like is to obtain a new variable (double or cell) with X columns from the cell array A and double matrix B every time a condition is verified. The condition would be if column Y (from A) and Z (from B) match. For instance:
Cell array A:

> '19970102' '00000127' 'MORRISON' '00148' 'BA'
>
> '19970102' '00010121' 'GALLITANO A' '00001382' 'ALEX'
>
> '19970102' '00031783' 'HOPSON' '00039' 'EDW'
>
> '19970102' '00040486' 'STRUM' '00003' 'CHI'
>
> '19970102' '00003337' 'KATICA H' '00001929' 'RAYMOND'

Double Matrix B:

> 19970101   31783   183
>
> 19970101   127 235
>
> 19970101   18290   183
>
> 19970101   835 01
>
> 19970101   40486   1976

What I would like to get in the ‘new’ variable:

> 19970101   31783   183 '19970102' '00031783' 'HOPSON' '00039' 'EDW'
>
> 19970101   127 235 '19970102' '00000127' 'MORRISON' '00148' 'BA'
>
> 19970101   18290   183
>
> 19970101   835 01
>
> 19970101   40486   1976 '19970102' '00040486' 'STRUM' '00003' 'CHI'

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot for your availability.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please post some code and explain why it doesn't work or doesn't give the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you're matching the 2nd column of A with the 2nd column of B. A is a cell array, B is a matrix. First, you need to convert the strings in the cell array to numeric values.

```
A2 = cellfun(@str2double, A(:,2));
```

This will produce a vector. Now, to match the values, use intersect:

```
[both, inA, inB] = intersect(A2, B(:,2));
```

Convert B to a cell array for concatenation:

```
Bcell = reshape(mat2cell(B(:), ones(numel(B),1)), size(B));
```

Concat matching rows:

```
[Bcell(inB,:) A(inA,:)]
```

To get the remaining rows of B (or A) that didn't match:

```
B(setdiff(1:size(B,1), inB),:)
```

I hope these tips help, if not answer your question. Good luck!

Comment: The Problem is that when I convert string to double (str2double) I get 'NaN' for all string elements I have, meaning I won't be successful at doing the match.

Comment: Now I get the following error: Error using mat2cell (line 107)
Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size,
[2615054        3].' Do you know what may I be doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd have to see your code to really have an idea. Have you looked at the documentation to mat2cell - they have some examples to help you know what it does.

Comment: I noticed a typo/error in my example code - this may actually fix your problem. Note that instead of B, I now use B(:) in the call to mat2cell.